# How to send email using aws-sdk for python but getting security token error?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I want to write python script using which I can send ses email.
I have go through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html) to send raw email and follow this procedure and code but I am getting this error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

In order to set credentials I have installed aws-cli and use aws configure to setup access key id and secret key but I am getting error about security token. I have gone to my profile's My security credentials and generated 
access key from there.

Comment: Use Django web framework it makes your work easy and reliable I have the working code for sending a mail with Django if you are interested then please let me know in the comment below

Comment: Thank you for the reply but actually I only want to send a raw email using boto3.